# ajax autocomplete extender inside formview throws javascript error

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm using .NET 4.0, AJAX 4.1.7.1005 and VS2010 C#.

I have written code using the ajax autocomplete several time without any issues.  I now have the need to put an autocomplete textbox in a formview that opens from a gridview selection of a record from a database and I can get the initial part of the autocomplete to work - being it grabs the data from the db and shows it in the selection listing.  The issue I have though is the OnClientPopulated and OnClientItemSelected calls to my javascript.  I tried putting the js in the page, in the formview and in the codebehind as a scriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock... but, regardless of where I put the js code, it throws this error:

> JavaScript runtime error: The value of the property 'OnSelectedItem' is null or undefined, not a Function object

If I remove the OnClientxxx calls the autocomplete works for the textbox but I need to get the other details to populate some hidden fields(not currently hidden for testing).  I'm calling a OnTextChanged event on the textbox to try and set the other textboxes' values.

I know it has to do with how it is rendered and how it is calling the scripts but I am still learning and haven't found a good answer yet in searching google/bing or here on SO.

Maybe I'm going about it in the wrong direction but any help is greatly appreciated.

My Code:

---

*aspx page*

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_approver1name" runat="server" Width="225px" Text='<%#Bind("APPROVER1_NAME")%>' AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txt_approver1name_TextChanged" />

<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender runat="server" BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx1" ID="autoComplete1" TargetControlID="txt_approver1name"
ServicePath="~/webservices/autocomplete.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" MinimumPrefixLength="3"
CompletionInterval="200" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="5" CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement"
CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem" CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem"
ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">

<Animations>
    <OnShow>
        <Sequence>
            <%-- Make the completion list transparent and then show it --%>
            <OpacityAction Opacity="0" />
            <HideAction Visible="true" />

            <%--Cache the original size of the completion list the first time
                the animation is played and then set it to zero --%>
            <ScriptAction Script="
                // Cache the size and setup the initial size
                var behavior = $find('AutoCompleteEx1');
                if (!behavior._height) {
                    var target = behavior.get_completionList();
                    behavior._height = target.offsetHeight - 2;
                    target.style.height = '0px';
                }"
            />

            <%-- Expand from 0px to the appropriate size while fading in --%>
            <Parallel Duration=".1">
                <FadeIn />
                <Length PropertyKey="height" StartValue="0" EndValueScript="$find('AutoCompleteEx1')._height" />
            </Parallel>
        </Sequence>
    </OnShow>
    <OnHide>
        <%-- Collapse down to 0px and fade out --%>
        <Parallel Duration=".1">
            <FadeOut />
            <Length PropertyKey="height" StartValueScript="$find('AutoCompleteEx1')._height" EndValue="0" />
        </Parallel>
    </OnHide>
</Animations>
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>

<asp:TextBox ID="hdn_txt_approver1username" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("APPROVER1_USERNAME")%>' />
<asp:TextBox ID="hdn_txt_approver1email" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("APPROVER1_EMAIL")%>' />
<asp:TextBox ID="hdn_txt_approver1emplid" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("APPROVER1_EMPLID")%>' />
```

*cs page*

```
    protected void txt_approver1name_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt_approver1name = (TextBox)FormView_UpdateMode.FindControl("txt_approver1name");
    string cleanname = txt_approver1name.Text.ToString();
    string[] split = cleanname.Split(new Char[] { '|' });
    txt_approver1name.Text = split[0].Trim();

    string onListPopulated = "<script type='text/javascript'>" +
                    "function onListPopulated {" +
                    "var completionlist = $find('AutoCompleteEx1').get_completionList();" +
                    "completionlist.style.width = 'auto';}</script>";

    string OnSelectedItem = "<script type='text/javascript'>" +
                    "function OnSelectedItem(source, eventArgs) {" +
                    "var empdetails = eventArgs.get_value();" +
                    "empdetails = empdetails.split('|');" +
                    "var edTitle = empdetails[0];" +
                    "var edEmpID = empdetails[1];" +
                    "var edEmail = empdetails[2];" +
                    "var edUsername = empdetails[3];" +
                    "var approver1email = document.getElementById('<%=(TextBox)FormView_UpdateMode.FindControl('hdn_txt_approver1email').ClientID %>');" +
                    "var approver1emplid = document.getElementById('<%=(TextBox)FormView_UpdateMode.FindControl('hdn_txt_approver1emplid').ClientID %>');" +
                    "var approver1username = document.getElementById('<%=(TextBox)FormView_UpdateMode.FindControl('hdn_txt_approver1username').ClientID %>');" +
                    "approver1email.value = edEmail;"+
                    "approver1emplid.value = edEmpID;"+
                    "approver1username.value = edUsername;" +
                    "</script>";


    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.FormView_UpdateMode, this.GetType(), "onListPopulated", onListPopulated, true);
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.FormView_UpdateMode, this.GetType(), "OnSelectedItem", OnSelectedItem, true);

    var acx = (AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender)FormView_UpdateMode.FindControl("autoComplete1");
    acx.OnClientItemSelected = "OnSelectedItem";
    acx.OnClientPopulated = "onListPopulated";
}
```

If you need any other details I can provide.
Thank you in advance!

Additionally, I will need to have two autocomplete fields in this formview so if I can get one working then I can work out the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I, sort-of resolved this on my own by just putting hidden fields outside of the formview and then adding an on change event to populate the visible fields in the formview with the values of the the hidden fields.  Yes, some extra steps to get my results but it works never-the-less.